# SSRS Site Not Loading CSS/Functionality

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have an existing SSRS instance which loads the all pages/reports as expected without an issue (as below).

[image]

We've recently created a second instance, running on the same server, which doesn't appear to load any CSS or the expected SSRS functionality - just a basic HTML page.

[image]

However when you click through the links on the second instance and run the report the design then appears to load correctly.

Both instances use the same execution count and we get the same result regardless of browser.

We're using SQL Server 2012.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried re-creating the virtual directory through the `RS Config Manager`? Load up the tool, connect to your instance, go to `Report Manager URL`, and set the `Virtual Directory` to another path. Click `Apply`, and let it run through it's paces. Once it's completed, rename it back to `genero` and click `Apply`. At this point I would also restart the `SQL Server Reporting Services` service as well. Perhaps something wasn't published at initial deployment and this will alleviate that. Worth a shot at least.

Answer (score 2):

Trobbins pointed me in the right direction; basically I was using the link from the Web Service URL rather than the Report Manager URL.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbXTc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gGid.png

After swapping these around the site functionality now loads correctly.

So to summarise you need to use the URL provided in the **Report Manager URL** option, **not** the **Web Service URL**.